# docker traefik error key has already been defined

Tags: docker, traefik

I restarted a server with docker containers and traefik, everthing was fine before that but now I have this

> 2022/10/24 18:45:08 command traefik error: toml: line 23 (last key "certificatesResolvers.myResolver.acme"): Key 'certificatesResolvers.myResolver.acme.httpChallenge' has already been defined.

Error from `docker logs`

And the docker container is always restarting

I tried changing "myResolver" by something else but it gives the same error, none of my sites work because of that.

EDIT:

toml file:

```
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.web]
    address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.web.http]
      [entryPoints.web.http.redirections]
        [entryPoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint]
          to = "websecure"
          scheme = "https"

  [entryPoints.websecure]
    address = ":443"

[api]
dashboard = true

[providers.docker]
  endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"

[certificatesResolvers.myResolver.acme]
  email = "myMail@gmail.com"
  storage = "acme.json"
  httpChallenge = true
  [certificatesResolvers.myResolver.acme.httpChallenge]
    entryPoint = "web"
```

docker-compose :

```
version: '3.2'
networks:
  myNetwork:
    external: true
services:
  reverse-proxy:
    restart: always
    image: traefik:v2.6
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./acme.json:/acme.json
    networks:
      - myNetwork
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.reverse-proxy.rule=Host('dashboard.com')"
      - "traefik.http.routers.reverse-proxy.service=api@internal"
      - "traefik.http.routers.reverse-proxy.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.reverse-proxy.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.reverse-proxy.tls.certresolver=myResolver"
```

there is only those 2 files and the acme.json

Comment: You'll need to show us how you're configuring traefik. Please update your question to include your toml file and any other sources of configuration information.

Comment: @larsks edited, as I said before, everything was fine until I restart the server where traefik is.
Is there a way to delete an existing resolver? it is maybe that after the restart the container is trying to recreate the resolver instead of reusing it I don't know I am not traefik expert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!
I just found that "httpChallenge=true" line was not an acceptable line, weird thing is that it was working before :/

old traefik.toml

```
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.web]
    address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.web.http]
      [entryPoints.web.http.redirections]
        [entryPoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint]
          to = "websecure"
          scheme = "https"

  [entryPoints.websecure]
    address = ":443"

[api]
dashboard = true

[providers.docker]
  endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"

[certificatesResolvers.myResolver.acme]
  email = "myMail@gmail.com"
  storage = "acme.json"
  httpChallenge = true
  [certificatesResolvers.myResolver.acme.httpChallenge]
    entryPoint = "web"
```

new traefik.toml

```
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.web]
    address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.web.http]
      [entryPoints.web.http.redirections]
        [entryPoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint]
          to = "websecure"
          scheme = "https"

  [entryPoints.websecure]
    address = ":443"

[api]
dashboard = true

[providers.docker]
  endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"

[certificatesResolvers.myResolver.acme]
  email = "myMail@gmail.com"
  storage = "acme.json"
  [certificatesResolvers.myResolver.acme.httpChallenge]
    entryPoint = "web"
```

It now works and I have my certificates on my sites.